# Where do I see Javascript code for this codepen form?

Tags: html, css, codepen

I can't see any here https://codepen.io/larirabello/pen/eojQww

There are only Html, Css but no Javascript ?

I can't see any clue in the html :

```
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Sign Up
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="column" id="main">
            <h1>Sign Up </h1>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail </label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="E-mail">
              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div>
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <svg width="67px" height="578px" viewBox="0 0 67 578" version="1.1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com -->
              <title>Path</title>
              <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
              <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path
                  d="M11.3847656,-5.68434189e-14 C-7.44726562,36.7213542 5.14322917,126.757812 49.15625,270.109375 C70.9827986,341.199016 54.8877465,443.829224 0.87109375,578 L67,578 L67,-5.68434189e-14 L11.3847656,-5.68434189e-14 Z"
                  id="Path" fill="#F9BC35"></path>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="column" id="secondary">
            <div class="sec-content">
              <h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that that is your own post where JS code somehow went missing ? Edit: there is some external javascript linked to it; you can see it after clicking the cogwheel button.

Answer (score 0):

You can not see any JavaScript because the codepen is not using any custom JavaScript. The codepen is actually importing bootstrap. you can view more about bootstrap modals [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/)

[image: codepen screenshot]